# Getting strange error from pip-pypy when trying to install PySide

Tags: python, pip, pyside, pypy

I'm using PyPy as my Python implementation, and thus, I installed `pip-pypy` (I'm on Arch). I then tried the following command:

```
pip-pypy install PySide
```

This fails with the following error:

```
error: Failed to locate the Python library with /opt/pypy/lib/libpython2.7.so, /opt/pypy/lib/libpython2.7.so.1, /opt/pypy/lib/libpython2.7.a
```

I'm a bit confused by this, and would like to know what I should do to make this work.

Comment: Were you not able to install PySide as per [these instructions](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Linux#565b27da0cfd6a77f36f7a292d6c9d21)

Comment: I could install it - however, when I tried to run the tutorial at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Hello-World-in-PySide using Pypy, I got a 'No module named PySide' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Pyside is not supported by PyPy [1][2] at this stage so you won't be able to use it from PyPy.

A version of Pyside patched for PyPy was in development [3] but it is now stalled and known not to work.

Let's hope this changes in the near future.

I between, you can try wxWidgets [4], Tkinter [5] and even GTK through pgi [6].

**References:**

- [1] PyPy compatibility wiki page: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/Home
- [2] PySide Mailing list: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/pyside/2012-May/000403.html
- [3] PyPy-dev Mailing list: https://mail.python.org/pipermail//pypy-dev/2014-February/012239.html
- [4] http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/05/running-wxpython-on-top-of-pypy.html
- [5] http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-tkinter-and-idle-with-pypy.html
- [6] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgi

Answer (score 1):

It has changed, although in the not-so-near future. You can install PySide 6.3 now on PyPy. See https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-details-on-the-new-6.3-release